# AWS RDS: Renew SSL/TLS certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I have a NestJS application connecting to a Postgres database hosted in AWS RDS. This is my TypeORM config:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres' as 'postgres',
        host: configService.getStringVar('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: configService.getNumberVar('DATABASE_PORT'),
        username: configService.getStringVar('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.getStringVar('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.getStringVar('DATABASE_DATABASE'),
        schema: configService.getStringVar('DATABASE_SCHEMA'),
        entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: false,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    })
```

As you see, I'm not configuring anything related to SSL.

On the other hand, my AWS RDS database's SSL/TLS certificate is about to expire. Since the client connection is not using SSL certificate, I assume there won't be consequences when SSL certificate expires and/or nothing will happen (I mean, client will keep connecting) if I renew the AWS RDS SSL cerficate. Am I right?

Comment: "I'm not configuring anything related to SSL"   I don't see a configuration *not* to use TLS either.  I would just Update the cert on the RDS server; it's not hard and should be pretty safe and not cause an interruption https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html